# My Jakks / Namco 5-in-1 Plug and Play TV console has messed up video. Any ideas on how to fix/troubleshoot?

Tags: controllers, monitor

I have a Jakks / Namco 5-in-1 Plug and Play TV console.  For reference, this is what it looks like:
[image]

When I start it up, the audio works fine, but the picture is messed up.  This is the game select screen:
[image]

I can play games just fine, except for not being able to see them very well.  The connection to my TV is a dual RCA cable (one audio, one video).

Any ideas on what might be wrong, or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: RCA cables do not work well with modern HDTVs if that is what you are using.